# Using JOOX to filter xml data from REST endpoint

Tags: java, xml-parsing, joox

I've a REST endpoint that returns XML like this (the XML is of course bigger say around 10,000 blocks of data vs the 3 blocks I show in this example):

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
  <book id="bk101">
    <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
    <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>44.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
    <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
  </book>
  <book id="bk102">
    <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
    <title>Midnight Rain</title>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
    <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,       an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen       of the world.</description>
  </book>
  <book id="bk103">
    <author>Corets, Eva</author>
    <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
    <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology       society in England, the young survivors lay the       foundation for a new society.</description>
  </book>
</catalog>
```

Now I want to filter it on the fly based on certain tag value and just retain the blocks where tag=value (and then cast it into an object). 
For this example I'd like to keep only the books where genre=Fantasy and just cast the fields price, title and author to my BookInfo object. I want to avoid creating a xml parser. Can I do it with JOOX ?

Comment: Yes, you can. This is a basic use-case for JOOX. See projects github page for all the details you need: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOX. If it does not work for you, come back here and explain what you tried and what does not work.

Answer (score 1):

jOOX allows for using two types of query languages for these kinds of use-cases:

#### CSS Selectors

Because jOOX is inspired by [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), CSS selectors are available through the [`Match.find()`](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOOX/javadoc/latest/org/joox/Match.html#find-java.lang.String-) method. They're useful for very simple queries. Internally, they're translated to XPath, which is the second query language:

#### XPath

XPath is the ideal query language for searching content in XML documents. You can use the [`Match.xpath()`](https://www.jooq.org/products/jOOX/javadoc/latest/org/joox/Match.html#xpath-java.lang.String-) method to search for fantasy books, for instance:

```
Match match = $(xml).xpath("/catalog/book[genre=\"Fantasy\"]");
```

From there on, you can further process your books, e.g. printing them:

```
$(xml).xpath("/catalog/book[genre=\"Fantasy\"]")
      .each(System.out::println);
```

Or mapping them into your `BookInfo` type:

```
List<BookInfo> books = 
$(xml).xpath("/catalog/book[genre=\"Fantasy\"]")
      .map(book -> new BookInfo(
          $(book).child("price").text(BigDecimal.class),
          $(book).child("title").text(),
          $(book).child("author").text()
      ));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Lukas!